# How do I remove a symlink?

Tags: macos, symlink

I just created the [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) `sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib` and am wondering: how can I get rid of it if I wanted to? How would I do this?

Comment: Related: *[Remove a symlink to a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210120/remove-a-symlink-to-a-directory)*

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Remove it just like you would any other file: `rm /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib`. rm will remove the symlink itself, not the file the link is pointing at.

Comment: for me on macOs it the command line jus stopped waiting for something I gave up waiting and deleted the symlink from Finder.

Answer (score 58):

You can use the unlink command: `unlink /path/to/sym/link`

Deleting the file within [Finder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finder_(software)) also works fine. It will have a little shortcut icon on it.

Answer (score 15):

Just run:

```
rm /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

This will remove the file (i.e. the symlink).

Alternatively you may use unlink:

```
unlink /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

Answer (score 4):

Somehow I had a symlink to a non-existing folder. I don't have any idea how it happened, but to remove it I found the easiest way was open in [Finder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finder_(software)) and manually delete it. I came to this decision after an hour wasted on trying to delete it with the [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS)#Terminal).

Answer (score 3):

I had a link pointing to a folder with short-name "testproject":
you make that with this command

```
ln -s /Users/SHERIF/repo/test  testproject
```

I had to change the folder name to something else for some reasons when I run the command unlink pointing to the old folder directory it didn't work.

I tried to only `unlink testproject` to remove the short-name so I can re-use the same name again and link to the newly named folder. it did work fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove that link with `sudo rm /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib`

Comment: That ought to come with some risk assessment. What could get the file ***deleted*** (zapped, wiped out, gone to the eternal bitfields) and not just the symbolic link? Just two extra characters?

Answer (score 0):

To remove a symlink, you can use the `unlink` command in the terminal. For example, if the symlink is called `mysymlink`, the command would be `unlink mysymlink`.