# Can a symlink negatively affect the original file?

Tags: shell, github, command-line-interface

I want to upload a markdown file named "original.md" to a repo, but it has to stay named like that. I want the "README.md" which GitHub displays automatically to link to it.

```
$ ln -s original.md README.md
```

It creates a link, then the files look like so:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 username username  32K Nov  8 11:33 original.md
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 username username   15 Nov 12 02:23 README.md -> original.md
```

Now if I stage, commit, and push to git everything will look fine, the "original.md" will display through README.md.

However, what if I change my mind one day and decide that I don't need the README.md anymore because I don't want my files in Git anymore? Let's say I delete it:

```
$ rm README.md
```

While this removal have any negative effect on the "original.md" file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a symlink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932906/how-do-i-remove-a-symlink)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is a symlink... you can remove it safely. If you remove `original.md` instead the symlink will not work anymore.

You can just have a look https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-symbolic-links-in-linux-using-the-ln-command/