# How to delete a symbolic link in python?

Tags: python, symlink

I have been trying to delete some symbolic links in my working directory, but I am facing some issues.

`os.remove` also removes the actual contents of the original folder of the link

`os.shutil` throws up an error in case of symbolic links.

Is there a way to remove a symbolic link using python commands without destroying the original content?

Thanks

Comment: Strange, `os.remove()` does not remove the original file for me, only the symlink (tried with Python 2.7.2 and 3.1.4).

Comment: It does not remove the original file neither at my system (Python 2.7.1)

Comment: Smth worth-looking on symlinks: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12678252/110118
(note: shutil.rmtree would fail to remove a link, despite os.path.osdir() saying the path pertains to a dir)

Comment: The question is about links to directories, not links to files. Removing links to directories does not work for me either. Python 2.6

Comment: What is `os.shutil`?

Comment: @MOnsDaR Removing links to directories works for me. Python 2.7.5, CentOS 7

Answer (score 57, accepted):

[`os.unlink()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.unlink) works for me. It removes the symlink without removing the directory that it links to.

Comment: Python 2.7 documentation say about unlink: `This is the same function as remove();`, how did it solved the problem?

Comment: This solution does not work on Windows for directory links created via `mklink /D`. See my answer below if that's your problem.

Comment: How does it work recursively to all symbolic links in a directory?

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer does not work on Windows with links created via `mklink /D`. If that is your problem the answer has been posted in this question: [Delete Symlink to directory on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554135/cant-delete-unlink-a-symlink-to-directory-in-python-windows)

The following code should work on both systems:

```
if(os.path.isdir(targetLink)):
    os.rmdir(targetLink)
else:
    os.unlink(targetLink)
```

Answer (score 6):

Sorry,my Bad, I had made a stupid programming mistake :  I was stupidly deleting the source instead of the links.

The correct answer is by @samfrances.

`os.unlink` does the trick.

In addition to this, here some other tips if you want to clear a directory using python:

Definitely not threadsafe, but you get the idea...

```
def rm(obj):

    if os.path.exists(obj):
        if os.path.isdir(obj):
            if os.path.islink(obj):
                 os.unlink(obj)
            else:
                shutil.rmtree(obj)
        else:
            if os.path.islink(obj):
                os.unlink(obj)
            else:
                os.remove(obj)
```

Comment: do `if os.path.exists(obj)` then `if os.path.islink` then `if os.path.isdir`. that way you don't need to have os.unlink twice.

Answer (score 3):

in Python 3.4 and above, 
If link is a file, use `unlink()`.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> p = Path('/some/file/')
>>> p.unlink()
```

If the path points to a directory, use Path.rmdir() instead.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> p = Path('/some/dir/')
>>> p.rmdir()
```

Answer (score 1):

If the directory name contains a trailing slash, the linux `rm` command will follow the link and try to delete the directory. See [Remove a symlink to a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210120/remove-a-symlink-to-a-directory). The `os.remove` [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.remove) says that it will give you an `OSError` if you try to remove a directory but maybe that doesn't always happen in the case of symlinks.

Comment: It says `OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'test/'` for me. Probably it's implementation dependent.

Comment: I don't have python handy. I should have said that this was a guess. I've edited the answer.

Comment: @JohnWatts Your answer is true, but this holds true only for symlinks created by the shell. symlinks created by `os.symlink` still give the same issue

Comment: @all: Edit:: Sorry... My Bad... I had made a stupid programming mistake... Was stupidly deleting the source instead of the links...gahhh... wasted almost a day on this...