# How to delete the symlink along with the source directory

Tags: python, shell, directory

I would like to delete the symlink along with the source directory.

For example -

```
ls -lrt
testsymlink -> /user/temp/testdir
```

I would like to remove both `testsymlink` and `/user/temp/testdir`. Consider that I know the only the symlink name.

Any utility with python will do great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the result of `os.path.realpath` to detect and delete the symlink target. Example:

```
import os

# ./foo -> ./bar
filepath = "./foo"

if (os.path.realpath(filepath) != filepath):
    targetpath = os.path.realpath(filepath)

os.remove(filepath)
if (targetpath):
     os.remove(targetpath)
```

Comment: Works fine as expected. Thanks Tim!

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: I didn't see that you wanted a solution in python: This is all only relevant in a unix shell. Although you *could* wrap the two commands below in a `os.system()` call, I highly suggest you follow Tim's answer.

To get the path of the object the symlink is pointing to, you can use `readlink`:

```
$ readlink testsymlink
/user/temp/testdir
```

To delete the object the symlink is pointing to, you can pass the output of `readlink` to `rm`:

```
$ rm -r `readlink testsymlink`
```

The backticks cause the command inside of them to be run, and then replaced with its own output. Finally, to remove the symlink itself, we simply run:

```
$ rm testsymlink
```

Comment: Well, the question is also tagged `shell`, so +1 for an equally nice solution. I'm just not sure if the assumption _Tim's answer below_ will always hold true ;-)

Comment: @staticfloat - I was looking for Python Utility. Both solutions are very good. readlink is new to me. Thanks!

Comment: @Lukas: Below, Above, these concepts are meaningless in mighty cyberspace.  :P