# Can't delete / unlink a symlink to directory in python & windows

Tags: python, windows, symlink

**edited**

i created symlinks to a directory, on Widnows7, using `mklink` command line:

```
mklink /d books config
```

i'm trying to delete it with python 2.7 (still on windows).

```
>>> os.remove('books')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    sym = symlink_to_dir
    os.unlink(sym) # 
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'books'
```

there are no restrictions on that machine, i'm admin,
and i didn't have problems to delete it from Windows  <strike>(del books)</strike>

There's no problem deleting a link to a file (as opposed to a dir).

why is that?

**edit** "del" didn't work, it just didn't return an error.

Comment: What does "there are no permissions on that machine" mean? Taken literally, it makes the answer pretty obvious: if you have no permissions, you should be getting access denied for everything. But I can't figure out any way to take it that makes more sense…

Comment: Meanwhile, any chance the symlink is in use? For example have you `cd`'d to the symlink (or a subdirectory through the symlink) in a running cmd.exe shell?

Comment: One last thing: You almost certainly don't want `os.system('del '+sym)`. That gives you no way to tell whether it succeeded or failed, it will not work if `sym` has any spaces or various other special characters, etc. If you really need to run an external command, use `subprocess`, not `os.system`.

Comment: Also, is `'static'` the name of the file?

Answer (score 3):

oops, i overlooked it:

since it's a link to a directory, windows, unlike linux, consider the symlink as a directory, therefore:

from DOS:

```
c:\> rmdir symlink
```

from python:

```
>>> os.rmdir( 'symlink' )
```

and **NOT** "del symlink", nor "os.unlink()", nor "os.remove()".

This is how it looks like **in Linux**:

```
$ mkdir a
$ ln -s a b
$ rm b          #ok, since a symlink is treated as a file

$ ln -s a b
$ rmdir b       # error, not a file
rmdir: failed to remove `b': Not a directory
```

Comment: Yes, ```os.rmdir()``` is the correct way to remove a symlink to a directory on Windows. I can confirm that the contents of the original directory won't be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I will make a guess.  What you have may not be a symlink like the ones on *INX, but rather a hard link.  You should be able to os.remove() to remove the hard link.

Comment: Was about to say this when you responded. We need to know what options were used during `mklink`!