# "Symbolic" link to resolve requests to a folder outside public_html?

Tags: php, linux, apache, security, resolveurl

I have a lot of image and pdf files in a folder within the `public_html` directory, and I have a lot of scripts on public_html dynamically processing, creating and editing these files based on user requests.

Now the problem is that I've realized that having these files stored in folders in `public_html` isn't safe, maybe someone could just inject some script and delete them all! So what I want to do is move them outside public_html. However - since I have so very many scripts dealing with all these files, all the paths will be messed up. I am using scripts that use relative paths, (`/home/public_html/designs/product1/...`) as well as scripts that use absolute paths (`www.mydomain.com/designs/product1/...`).

I don't know much about symbolic links to be honest - I've read up some but I found it confusing since I'm not that good with Linux either.

My question is: is there any way that I can put some kind of symbolic link or connection, so that I can move all my product design files outside public_html, and yet don't have to change all my scripts to point to the new path? So maybe, some kind of code that resolves all `public_html/designs/` requests from my scripts to the new path? Maybe symbolic links isn't what I need here, but something else?

Answer (score 4):

create sysmbolic links is easy in linux

first go to public_html directory  :

```
/home/public_html/
```

then move designs directory to upper directory [ or every where you want ]
    mv designs ../

then create sysmbolic link to the real directory

```
ln -s ../designs designs
```

every thing will be work

Comment: And, how to remove the link is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210120/remove-a-symlink-to-a-directory