# some error with the 'ln' scripts

Tags: linux, windows, shell, go

anybody is familiar with the etcd project? Or we'd better forget the project when talk about this issue. The issue is

```
$ build
ln: `gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd': cannot overwrite directory
```

when exec the **build** shell
and the content is:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

if [ ! -h gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd ]; then
    mkdir -p gopath/src/github.com/coreos/
    ln -s ../../../.. gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd
fi

export GOBIN=${PWD}/bin
export GOPATH=${PWD}/gopath
export GOFMTPATH="./bench ./config ./discovery ./etcd ./error ./http ./log main.go ./metrics ./mod ./server ./store ./tests"

# Don't surprise user by formatting their codes by stealth
if [ "--fmt" = "$1" ]; then
    gofmt -s -w -l $GOFMTPATH
fi

go install github.com/coreos/etcd
go install github.com/coreos/etcd/bench
```

Some addition:
My system is windows 7
I run the shell on git bash.
**issue reproduce:**

```
step1: open the git bash
step2: git clone git@github.com:coreos/etcd.git
step3: cd etcd
step4: build
```

Comment: I don't see how `java` is relevant here. I've removed it.

Comment: Strange, I can't even issue such an error with `ln -s`.

Comment: Okay, tell me: if you go to the directory with build script, and sequently issue the commands `mkdir -p gopath/src/github.com/coreos/` and `ln -s ../../../.. gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd` — does the error appears?

Comment: @Hi-Angel  Can you please see my edit ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in "[Git Bash Shell fails to create symbolic links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19550674/6309)" (since you are using the script in a git bash on Windows 7)

> the `ln` that shipped with msysGit simply tries to copy its arguments, rather than fiddle with links. This is because links only work (sort of) on NTFS filesystems, and the MSYS team didn't want to reimplement ln.
>
> A workaround is to run `mklink` from Bash.
> This also allows you to create either a [Symlink or a Junction](https://superuser.com/questions/343074/directory-junction-vs-directory-symbolic-link).

So 'ln' wouldn't work as expected by default, in the old shell that ships with Git for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Here's solution. Tbh it is a workaround, but since you're on Windows, I don't see another way.

Start a command line, and enter there to the directory with the script. There should be a path `gopath/src/github.com/coreos/` (if no such a path, you must create it). Next issue a command

```
mklink /D "gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd" "../../../../"
```

Next you should edit the build script to delete a lines with creation symlink and a directory. E.g.

```
#!/bin/sh -e

export GOBIN=${PWD}/bin
export GOPATH=${PWD}/gopath
export GOFMTPATH="./bench ./config ./discovery ./etcd ./error ./http ./log main.go ./metrics ./mod ./server ./store ./tests"

# Don't surprise user by formatting their codes by stealth
if [ "--fmt" = "$1" ]; then
    gofmt -s -w -l $GOFMTPATH
fi

go install github.com/coreos/etcd
go install github.com/coreos/etcd/bench
```

Note, that I am just removed 4 lines of code. Next you run the script, and this should work.

Comment: when exec the D:\Git\etcd>mklink \D gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd ../../../..  it says “unavailable switch - 'src'”

Comment: @user3231931, oh, sorry, I wrote a wrong slash. It should be `mklink /D gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd ../../../../`. I will edit the answer.

Comment: I've tried this. the same result “unavailable switch - 'src'” it's wired.

Comment: @user3231931 hm... Try then add a quotes, like this: `mklink /D "gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd" "../../../../"`

Comment: yes, now it works by add the quotes. I try other parts.

Comment: Good workaround, more detailed than my answer who mentioned first the issue. +1

Comment: @Hi-Angel sign.another issue when exec the build shell after remove the `if [ ! -h gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd ]; then
 mkdir -p gopath/src/github.com/coreos/
 ln -s ../../../.. gopath/src/github.com/coreos/etcd
fi` can't load package: package github.com/coreos/etcd: open d:\git\etcd\gopath\src\github.com\coreos\etcd: Access is denied.

Comment: @user3231931 I know why is this. The `../../../../` path refers to an unxistent directory that is above even "disk D:". I think that the script probably should had some other relevant directory there, and I have no idea what the directory this could be.

Comment: @user3231931 this is really weird. Perhaps you should ask about it(about the directory) on the mailing list of the `etcd`, or on IRC.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Ok. I will ask about it on the mailing list, thank you so much

Comment: @VonC, if you occasionally thought that I am saw your answer, and decided to stole it, this isn't true. I didn't refreshed the page, and doesn't saw an answers at the moment. I didn't even knew what the issue was with `ln` and what `etcd` is. I just saw the script, after some comments figured out, that the author using Windows®, and BASH probably executed via some emulating interpreter that is failing on `ln`, and recall that the Windows has some support of symlink. Then googled what the command was to create these, and — voilà.

Comment: @Hi-Angel The thought never cross my mind. I still consider your answer better and more complete than mine, and I am glad you took the time to investigate the issue further.