# how to create file symlink by using Nodejs on Windows?

Tags: node.js, symlink

I'm making a tiny tool which is coding in Node.js and it would create file symlink on both Windows and OSX. However I get stuck at how to create symlink on Windows.

First, I tried `fs.symlink` and `junction` option, but `junction` only works for directory on Windows.

Secondly, by referring to [Git Bash Shell fails to create symbolic links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641864/git-bash-shell-fails-to-create-symbolic-links), I tried to directly call `cmd <<< mklink SOURCE TARGET` by using of `shelljs.exec`, it never returned, node console hung.

Thirdly, I created a shell script named 'symlink.sh', invoked this script by child_process.spawn, I got `Error: spawn ENOENT`.

Now I've no idea, how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: I did not know there was symlinks in windows...

Comment: @john, there is, http://devtidbits.com/2009/09/07/windows-file-junctions-symbolic-links-and-hard-links/

Comment: you always learn something new. Never heard of anyone using the though...

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`lnk`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lnk) which is an OS-agnostic wrapper around the more specific tools.