# Add symlink file as file using Git on Windows

Tags: windows, git, symlink

I have a big (more than 1000 files) VS C# project in git. I need to create a small demo project and use ten files from the big project. To create this new project, I added ten files with mklink (symlink) from the big project to the small. All changes in corresponding files in the big and small project are identical. Now I need to add the small project to a different (my own) git repo.

But symlink will not add in git :

> (error: readlink("X.cs"): Function not implemented)

How to add the X.cs (symlink) file in git as a regular file?

I need all changes in X.cs (in big project) to be moved to X.cs (small project).

Comment: The error is clear: the git client doesn't know how to handle Windows symlinks (the symlink is just some metadata in the NTFS node). Don't good-old shortcuts work (in both VStudio and git)?

Comment: Thanks. I understand error. I must have one file in two directory/project. Th symlink good idea for this but bad for git.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Symlinks in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5917249/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git has problems with individual file links but it has no problem with directory symbolic links(mklink /d  ). Therefore move your image files to another directory in your big project and create directory link in your git repo to this directory.

See below for example.

> P:\denemeler\gitdeneme1>mklink /d linkDirectory P:\puzzles
>
> Created symbolic link : linkDirectory <<===>> P:\puzzles
>
> P:\denemeler\gitdeneme1>git status 
>   On branch master Untracked files:
>   (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
>
> ```
>     linkDirectory/
> ```
>
> nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to
>   track)
>
> P:\denemeler\gitdeneme1>git add linkDirectory
>
> P:\denemeler\gitdeneme1>git status
>
> On branch master Changes to be
>   committed:   (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)
>
> ```
>     new file:   linkDirectory/Juggle Fest Question.txt
>     new file:   linkDirectory/jugglefest.txt
>     new file:   linkDirectory/triangle.txt
>     new file:   linkDirectory/triangleQuestion.txt
> ```
>
> P:\denemeler\gitdeneme1>git commit -m "new files"
>
> [master 0c7d126] new
>   files  4 files changed, 14150 insertions(+)  create mode 100644
>   linkDirectory/Juggle Fest Question.txt  create mode 100644
>   linkDirectory/jugglefest.txt  create mode 100644
>   linkDirectory/triangle.txt  create mode 100644
>   linkDirectory/triangleQuestion.txt
>
> P:\denemeler\gitdeneme1>echo "aa" > p:\puzzles\newFile.txt
>
> P:\denemeler\gitdeneme1>git status
>
> On branch master Untracked files:
>   (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
>
> ```
>     linkDirectory/newFile.txt
> ```
>
> nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to
>   track)

Comment: After >>C:\xampp\Test\files\scss>git add linkDirectory<< I am getting an error:
 ```C:\xampp\Test\files\scss>git add linkDirectory
error: readlink("files/scss/linkDirectory"): Function not implemented
error: unable to index file files/scss/linkDirectory
fatal: adding files failed```

Comment: I everytime get error:

`error: readlink("FOLDER"): Function not implemented
error: unable to index file FOLDER
fatal: adding files failed`

Comment: This answer is not correct I still get the same error.

Answer (score 16):

If adding symlinks to the index fails  with error `error: readlink("..."): Function not implemented`, try to find this line in the local or global config:

```
[core]
    symlinks = false
```

You need to set `symlinks = true` for a successful push. **Default value (=true) if parameter does not exist or is not working correctly** and it depends on the settings with which the repository was created.

**Hardlinks do not work with GIT**, as the file and hardlink are stored as separate files.

It works the same with git version 2.8 or above (I did not check versions less than 2.8)

Comment: 2.8.1 on Windows, git is simply sending the target path instead of the content.

Comment: Yes, git store path to file. It is symlink. When you clone or pull repository with symlink, only administrator can create symlink. Change windows config to solve this: http://superuser.com/questions/124679/how-do-i-create-a-link-in-windows-7-home-premium-as-a-regular-user

Comment: If someone is interested the path to local git config is: `/.git/config`.

Comment: you can simply use the command `git config core.symlinks true`

Answer (score 10):

> The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.
>   The solutions given there isn't enough and isn't working.

There are still issues with the latest Git 2.12 on Windows (February 2017, 18 months after the OP's question)

In the context of working on what was called `git-new-workdir` in 2015 (the ability, form one clone, to have multiple working tree: this ended up [being called `git worktree`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309)), the Git developers were asking how to reference those worktrees from the main cloned repo.
Would they be using `ln`? or its Windows equivalent `mklink`?

[This thread, at the time, highlighted the issues](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=143261302510955&w=2):

> > When running on Windows in MinGW, creating symbolic links via `ln` always failed.
> >     Using `mklink` instead of `ln` is the recommended method of creating links on Windows

That might be true, but not ideal: "[Git Bash Shell fails to create symbolic links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40914277/6309)" does mention:

> For my setup, that is Git for Windows 2.11.0 installed on Windows 8.1 **`export MSYS=winsymlinks:nativestrict`** does the trick as explained here: [git-for-windows/pull/156](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/pull/156)
>
> **It's important to launch the Git Bash shell as administrator as on Windows only administrators could create the symbolic links**. So, in order to make `tar -xf` work and create the required symlinks:
>
> - Run Git Bash shell as an administrator
> - Run `export MSYS=winsymlinks:nativestrict`
> - Run `tar`

See also "[Git Symlinks in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42137273/6309)", where the setup now (Git for Windows 2.10+) include symlink support:

[image: symlink supoprt]

You need to specify that during the clone:

```
git clone -c core.symlinks=true <URL>
```

And your CMD session needs to be run as admin.

Needless to say imposing that prerequisite on Windows users is a no-go (Windows in enterprise generally come with limited or no privilege elevation)

Yet, [PR 156](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/pull/156) does represent some Windows support for symlink, [released in Git For Windows 2.10 (Sept. 2016)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.10.0.windows.1).

---

It is telling that [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) ended up implementing the multiple working tree reference... by  *not* relying on symbolic links and by making the borrowee and borrowers aware of each other.

> When you are done with a linked working tree you can simply delete it.
>   The working tree's administrative files in the repository will eventually be removed automatically (see gc.pruneworktreesexpire in git config), or you can run git worktree prune in the main or any linked working tree to clean up any stale administrative files.

So no symbolic link there.

Comment: `And your CMD session needs to be run as admin.`
User can create symlinks after change windows setting: http://superuser.com/questions/124679/how-do-i-create-a-link-in-windows-7-home-premium-as-a-regular-user

Comment: @Avissian I agree... but you do have to be admin to change `SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege` ;) (http://superuser.com/a/126450/141)

Answer (score 0):

Git does indeed have trouble with symlinks on Windows. However, I don't think you even need symlinks for your problem. A simple workaround is to write a small *.bat script to copy the files in question from one repository to another on demand. With symlink, you don't need to run a script, which saves you a few seconds, but you get a problem that you can accidentally change file in small repository and have unwanted modification in big repository.

Comment: Copy is not good. You can forget where file changed. With symlink i have identical file all time. Best solution "say git" work with symlink file as usual file

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all your simlinks located in one ntfs partition,  if it is true, you can renew all simlinks to hardlinks, by some script with command, mklink /h... 
Hardlinks friendly for any CVS.

Comment: "Hardlinks friendly for any CVS"... and absolutely deadly for removing since any O/S will treat them as a legitimate folder reference and walk them during a delete. Unlink symlinks where just the link will be removed (not it's contents).