# Permission denied when creating symbolic links in git

Tags: windows, git, bash, permissions, githooks

there is a similar question, but the difference here is that I am working on Windows. I am running git on Windows (working in git bash tool) and I have successefully cloned my forked repository. Now I need to make symbolic link and it gives me `Permission denied`. I can make new dir for example in `.git` folder and I have also set `chmod /R 777` for `.git` directory, so it seems I have permissions.

I tried to run:
`rm -rf hooks` and then `ln -s ../git_hooks hooks`.

Comment: The `ln` command is giving you that error? What is the error **exactly**? What does `ls -la` in your working directory output?

Comment: Yes, `ln` is giving me error. Error is `ln: creating symbolic link hooks to ../git_hooks: Permission denied`. List is giving me `drwxr-xr-x    5 User Administ        0 Jul 28 17:24 hooks` - This is the line for `hooks` folder only.

Comment: You have a `hooks` directory in your working directory already?

Comment: Yes, but from now, when I run the second line (`ln`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be running into a basic incompatibility of ln on windows platforms (in this case within MINGW-MSYS). You can replace ln with a version that "does the right thing" on Windows; have a look at this:

[Git Bash Shell fails to create symbolic links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641864/git-bash-shell-fails-to-create-symbolic-links)

Comment: I have used this tool: http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html and I have created symbolic link. Thank you!

Comment: Why? NTFS offers links of many kids natively on Windows.

Comment: Just in case.. I am using WSL (ubuntu) + git on Windows (11). Git clone was done on WSL, I followed the procedure here (windows in dev mode, symlink=true, and so on..) and I still was stuck until I git clone FROM windows. Now, every step works.

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue on Windows and I did a couple of steps to resolve this :

1. Enabled core.symlinks by modifying git config

   git config --edit
2. Opened Git Bash as an Administrator and executed the git checkout command

This worked for me, hope it helps someone.

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me. The key part was running git as an Adminstrator, as I already had core.symlinks enabled

Comment: Running Git Bash as Administrator did it for me. There was no mention of `symlinks` in my git config.

Answer (score 0):

If you have are using Git for Windows *SDK*, you can install `winln` using the `pacman` package manager by running: `pacman -Su winln`

Then you can run: `winln -s target link`, it will check that you have SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege, otherwise it will fail. This is equivalent to running Window's `mklink.exe`.

I am surprise Git for Windows, does not ship with `winln` vs an `ln` command that does a copy without telling you that it did a copy.

Answer (score 0):

When installing git-bash for windows, there is an option called "Enable symbolic links". When I installed git-bash with that option I had the same issue as OP. So I installed the same setup (git-bash) again with that "Enable symbolic links" option unchecked. Then my issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a local web server on Windows (OpenServer, Laragon, Local), then start the server as an administrator. It worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).