# Invalid symbolic link cannot be removed ou updated

Tags: linux, ubuntu

A invalid symbolic link was created somehow.
It gives a error even when I try to list the directory.

```
mariodourado@DGF32402:~/dev/02/trash/FolhaPEAR$ ls -l
ls: cannot read symbolic link FolhaPEAR: Not a directory
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 2207 11007 9 Fev 26 16:44 FolhaPEAR
```

If I try to remove...

```
mariodourado@DGF32402:~/dev/02/trash/FolhaPEAR$ rm -rf FolhaPEAR 
mariodourado@DGF32402:~/dev/02/trash/FolhaPEAR$ ls -la
ls: cannot read symbolic link FolhaPEAR: Not a directory
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 2 2207  2000 0 Fev 26 17:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 2207  2000 0 Fev 26 17:23 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 2207 11007 9 Fev 26 16:44 FolhaPEAR
```

If I try to update it...

```
mariodourado@DGF32402:~/dev/02/trash/FolhaPEAR$ ln -sfn /etc/ FolhaPEAR
ln: accessing ‘FolhaPEAR’: Not a directory
```

Any sugestions on how to remove it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically the rm command should work if you move one up in your directory tree:
mariodourado@DGF32402:~/dev/02/trash/$ rm -rf FolhaPEAR

Comment: Still doesn't work.
mariodourado@DGF32402:~/dev/02/trash$ rm -rf FolhaPEAR/
rm: cannot remove ‘FolhaPEAR/’: Directory not empty

Comment: It looks like it might be the trailing slash: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210120/remove-a-symlink-to-a-directory

Comment: Without the slash, returns 'cannot remove ‘FolhaPEAR’: Directory not empty' also.