# How to make rm not delete symbolic links?

Tags: bash, git, terminal, rm, ln

So, I was getting rid of the unwanted files and I deleted some folder. After some time I saw another folder which appears red in `ls -la`. I knew I deleted the actual folder and thus I was very sad and tried to run `foremost` to recover but bad luck. Can anyone give me some good aliases/function that deletes like rm -rf but if that file is linked to other files then it won't delete. Like if `/usr/bin/a.py` is linked to `/root/a.py` and I run `rm -rf /usr/bin/a.py` then `/root/a.py` will be deleted. How can I prevent that from an alias?

Comment: There were two folder so i removed the junk one but other got removed :(

Comment: @DipsehSunrait : Removing a symbolic link only removes the link, not the file it is linked to, at least as long as you do not use `-r`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Joe W's answer is correct in saying `rm` typically does not delete the targets of symlinks, but to say that it "does not follow symlinks" is not quite accurate, at least on my system (GNU coreutils 8.25). And deleting files is a place where accuracy is pretty important! Let's take a look at how it behaves in a few situations.

If your symlink is to a *file*, rather than to a *directory*, there is no plausible way to accidentally delete the target using `rm`. You would have to do something very explicit like `rm "$(readlink file)"`.

Symlinks to directories, however, get a bit dicey, as you saw when you accidentally deleted one. Here's a test case we can use:

```
$ mkdir test1
$ touch test1/foo.txt
$ ln -s test1 test2
$ ls -lR
.:
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 soren soren 4096 Jun 29 17:02 test1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 soren soren    5 Jun 29 17:02 test2 -> test1

./test1:
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 soren soren 0 Jun 29 17:02 foo.txt
```

These are all safe:

- `rm test2` (deletes the symlink only)
- `rm -r test2` (deletes the symlink only)
- `rm -rf test2` (deletes the symlink only)
- `rm test2/` (`rm: cannot remove 'test2/': Is a directory` -- no action taken)
- `rm -rf *2` (or any other glob matching the symlink -- deletes the symlink only)

These are *not* safe:

- `rm -r test2/` (`rm: cannot remove 'test2/': Not a directory` -- but deletes the contents of the `test1` directory)
- `rm -rf test2/` (deletes the contents of the directory, leaves the symlink, no error)
- `rm -rf test2/*`  (deletes the contents of the directory, leaves the symlink, no error)

The last unsafe case is probably obvious behavior, at least to someone well-acquainted with the shell, but the two before it are quite a bit more subtle and dangerous, especially since tab-completing the name of `test2` will drop the trailing slash in for you!

It's interesting to note that `test` has similar behavior, considering a symlink to a directory with a trailing slash to be not a symlink but a directory, while a symlink without a trailing slash is *both*:

```
$ [ -L "test2" ] && echo "is link"
is link
$ [ -d "test2" ] && echo "is directory"
is directory
$ [ -L "test2/" ] && echo "is link"
$ [ -d "test2/" ] && echo "is directory"
is directory
```

Here's a [previous treatment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210120/remove-a-symlink-to-a-directory?rq=1) of "deleting a symlink to a directory without deleting the target," with a less thorough analysis of exactly what works and what doesn't but with a bunch of other useful information.

---

Unfortunately, I am not aware of any way to alias `rm` to prevent this mistake. I suppose you could write a function to parse the arguments to `rm` and warn you if any of them are symlinks that end with a trailing slash, something like this:

```
function rm {
    for i in "$@"; do
        if [[ $i =~ /$ ]] && [ -L "${i:0:-1}" ]; then
            read -rp "Really delete symlink '$i' with trailing slash (y/n)? " result
            [ "$result" != "y" ] && return
        fi
    done
    command rm "$@"
}
```

Use at your own risk, though! It passes shellcheck and it worked when I tested it, but implementing a wrapper on top of something as fundamental and dangerous as `rm` gives me the heebie-jeebies.

Two other potentially useful switches you might include in your alias/function would be `--one-file-system` (at least skips files past a symlink or mount onto a different drive) and, if you don't already use it, `-i` or `-I` to prompt when doing something potentially dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is behaving the way you're indicating. rm doesn't follow symlinks

- https://superuser.com/questions/520058/does-rm-r-follow-symbolic-links
- https://superuser.com/questions/382314/does-rm-rf-follow-symbolic-links

The only way you could delete something is if you did something like `rm -rf myFolder/*` where `myFolder` is a linked directory.

Comment: That's the problem: deleting a directory tree containing symlinks results in deletion of the linked content rather than just the symlink.  The same problem occurs if you delete a directory via FTP.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a directory tree which has nested symlinks, and you know (or can find out) where they are, you can first use `unlink` to remove the symlinks.

Recursive deletion of a directory tree containing symlinks is otherwise dangerous, particularly if you use FTP, which also leads to removal of the linked target as well.  (I have been bitten by that, which is why I am here.  IMO it is a major bug in the Linux shell, and worse than Windows allowing drag-and-drop to accidentally move a folder somewhere else - at least in the Windows case it hasn't been deleted.)